# How to import a method or use that from another class in python?

Tags: python

I have two classes in the same folder;
filename

- Filename: twisted, class name : Root,method :def render_GET(self, request):
- Filename: ladpConnector, class name:MyClass, method : getMachines(self)

I want to call getMachines from the first file, inside Root class.

I tried following options;

- `MyClass().getMachines()`

> from ldapConnector import Myclass
>
> ```
> MyClass().getMachines()
> ```

All gives issues, undefined method/undefined variable class Myclass etc..

What is teh right way to call that method?

Comment: In `from ldapConnector import Myclass` class name not is same case(`MyClass`)

Comment: @SatanDmytro it is right ..here it is typo..Thanks there was another spelling mistake..It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but you need to import that class in the file that has the Root class:

```
# twisted.py file
from ldapConnector import MyClass

class Root():
    def __init__(self):
        MyClass().getConnections()
```

Comment: I have print statement under MyClass init method also under getMachines(self) method. When I call from Twsited.py like  MyClass().getMachines()     , i see print from init method, not from getMachines() method.. Means, it is not calling getMachines.What Im doing wrong?

Comment: It works thanks..Forgot to annotate  @defer.inlineCallbacks in the  getMachines ()method

Answer (score 1):

To access files within the same module you need to do relative imports: `from .ldapConnector import MyClass` should work.